# Using paste when creating a pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, paste

I want to use the `paste` function in R when I am saving a file using the `pdf` function but I get this error:

> filename too long in pdf()

What can I do to overcome this problem?

Here is my script:

```
for (chromo in 1:22){

read.table(paste("locfile_less_chrloc_file_chr", chromo, ".txt.txt" , sep=""))-> chr

t(chr) -> chr_t

as.matrix(chr_t) -> chr_t_m

length(chr_t_m) -> len

pdf(paste("chr",chromo,".pdf", sep=""))
plot(1:len,chr_t_m, type= "l")
dev.off()

}
```

So, my guess is that the `pdf` function does not allow the `paste` function to be used. Is that correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you storing `read.table` result into `chr`?

Comment: yes and then transposing it, changing it to a matrix to get the length and then finally do the plot

Comment: I tried saving it as a jpeg, but because I am on OSX there was a crash... something about X11. Saving it as any picture format will do also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not store the pdf filename in an extra object?

```
chr<-"a"
pdfname<-paste0("chr",chr,".pdf")
pdf(file=pdfname)
```

This works directly by the way:
`pdf(file=paste0("chr",chr,".pdf"))`

To get a shorter filename, try:
`pdf(file=paste0("chr",names(chr)[1],".pdf"))`

Substitute 1 for the appropriate column number.

Comment: It is not working, I keep getting the same error: pdf file name too long

Comment: Filename is too long because you are storing an entire dataframe in your string.

Comment: Yes! I am using the same name as the object.

Comment: You can't have an entire dataframe as a pdf name.

Comment: No problem, I enjoyed it.